# What determines in Linux the permissions, a file is written with?

Tags: linux, file, permissions, copy

I have a technical user which writes a file to a directory. The file is automatically granted permissions (rw-r--r--).

What determines that/why is it exactly 644 instead of any other rights combination?

And what/how do I have to configure so that the automatic permissions when writing the file are rw-rw-rw / 666? 
I would like to refrain from a chmod after copying, as this causes continuous additional work - better that every file copied to this directory by that user gets these permissions.

..and bonus question: does this also cover moving a file there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is called the [umask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) and it could be set to 600, 644 or 666.

Answer (score 0):

floridopower - you have to modify the umask for that specific user , in order to do this , you have to see the default environment of the system user, run this: 
cat /etc/passwd | grep -i thenameoftheuser

And if you see anywhere /bin/bash in the returned string just run this command:
echo "umask 111" >> /home/thenameoftheuser/.bashrc

So if the user is a system user and the home directory of that user is located in the directory /home/ you can safely run the above commands and then run a test ( create a new file with that user and look at the permissions )